# Django- Unable to access values from DetailView model object

Tags: python, django

I am trying to create a chat application that has two models: one holding the chat room names and another holding the messages.

```
from django.db import models

class ChatRoom(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    professor = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


    class MessagesInChat(models.Model):
        room_name = models.ForeignKey(ChatRoom, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="message_room")
            user_name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
            message = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    
        def __str__(self):
            return str(self.user_name)
```

However, whenever I try to access these fields from the template, I get the following error:

> No messages in chat found matching the query

I did fill the models with dummy values before trying this.

The following are my views.py file and template I'm using:

## views.py

```
from django.views.generic import DetailView, ListView
from chat import models

class Chats(ListView):
    template_name = "chat_list.html"
    context_object_name = "chat_list"
    model = models.ChatRoom

    def get_queryset(self):
        return models.ChatRoom.objects.order_by("name")


class ChatPage(DetailView):
    model = models.MessagesInChat
    template_name = "chat.html"
    context_object_name = "chat_page"
```

## Template

```
<!-- 'm' stands for message --> 
    {%for m in chat_page.message_room.all%}
      <div class="p-3 mb-2 bg-light text-dark" style="margin-top:20px;">{{m.message}}</div>
      <div class="p-3 mb-2 bg-success text-white" style="margin-top:20px;">{{m.message}}</div>
    {%endfor%}
```

Also the urls.py file:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls import url
from chat.views import ChatPage, Chats


urlpatterns = [
    url('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$', Chats.as_view(), name="chat_page"),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>[-\w]+)/$', ChatPage.as_view(), name="chats")
]
```

This problem has been bugging me for a while. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What URL gives you the error, and what do you want to display on that page?

Comment: @Alasdair I would like to display the message saved in the textfield in the div tags. The 'chats' url is the one that displays the error

Answer (score 0):

If `pk` in the URL is the primary key of the `ChatRoom` instance, then you should use `model = models.ChatRoom` in the view.

```
class ChatPage(DetailView):
    model = models.ChatRoom
    template_name = "chat.html"
    context_object_name = "chat_page"
```

Comment: Oh wow! That worked. But why does this happen. Does ForeignKey class also make the key into a Primary Key?

Comment: I don’t understand your question. Why does what happen? The code in your question `model = models.MessagesInChat` doesn’t make sense. That tries to fetch a single message with that primary key, and show the details for that. You want to fetch a single chat room, then you follow the foreign key backwards with `chat_page.message_room.all` in the template to get the related messages.